# Javascript, PHP write html to file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, mpdf

I am using the MPDF library for php and I have a html file that gets converted into PDF download. My problem is that I want to take the innerHTML of the current page I am looking and download a file with the innerHTML right before I download it as a PDF. I am creating this with Codeigniter.

-Javascript function to update the page before print

```
function update_document(content)
{
    var info = document.getElementById(content).innerHTML;
    $.ajax
    ({
        type:"POST",
        url: '<?=base_url()?>employee_controller/download_document',
        data:{info:info}
    }); 
}
```

--How I am downloading the document **Note I'm using PHP Codeigniter

```
function download_document()
{
    $content=$this->input->post('info');
    $this->generate_pdf($content);
}

function generate_pdf($content)
{
    $file_name = "Test";
    include('plugins/MPDF/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf= new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $mpdf->Output($file_name.'.pdf','D');
    exit;
}
```

--HTML button to download

```
<li><a href="<?=base_url('employee_controller/download_document');?>" onclick="download_document('print')"><i class="icon"><img src="<?=base_url();?>icons/pdf.png"/></i>&nbsp;PDF</a></li>
```

This does not give me any errors, but it does not create the page. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why are you writing the contents of the document into a PHP file?  How do you actually serve up the download?

Comment: It does not have to be a php file, I just left it that way. The "$mpdf->Output($file_name.'.pdf','D');" is the line that initiates the download.

Comment: I guess I should have asked, why write to a file at all? You already have the data in memory, so why add the extra overhead of file i/o into the mix? Also you actually return the document content with the asynchronous call. What is the intent in doing this?

Comment: @MikeBrant the intent of doing this is so when I create the pdf of that document, it will have the information I just wrote to it.

Comment: OK. So still why the need to read the data back out from the file?  You still have it in memory.

Comment: @MikeBrant how else could I accomplish this then, without needing to write to the file?